# Yii2 queue job constructor Dependency Injection alternative

Tags: dependency-injection, yii2

I need to get dependencies in class that implements yii\queue\Job interface. In perfect world I would do something like this:

```
public function __construct(SomeInterface $service)
{
    $this->service = $service;
}

public function execute($queue)
{
    $this->service->doSomething();
}
```

Unfortunately yii2-queue doesn't support resolving dependencies in job handler constructor. For now I deal with it like this:

```
public function execute($queue)
{
    $service = Yii::$container->get(SomeInterface::class);
    $service->doSomething();
}
```

Maybe there is a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Can you create your Job class using `Yii::createObject()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dealt with it using factory method pattern and resolving dependencies from DI container in it. Altought there are some problems with serialization of heavy dependecies. To resolve that I used simple proxy.

```
$this->queue->push(FooJob::create($someId));

// (...)

class FooJob implements Job 
{
    public $id;

    private $fooService;

    private $heavyService;

    public function __construct(int $id, FooInterface $fooService)
    {
        $this->fooService = $fooService;
    }

    public static function create(int $id): self
    {
        return Yii::$container->get(static::class, [$id]);
    }

    public function execute(Queue $queue): void
    {
        $this->fooService->bar($this->id); // service available since construct
        $this->heavyService->bark($this->id); // service available since first call
    }

    public function getHeavyService(Queue $queue): HeavyInterface
    {
        if (!$this->heavyService) {
            $this->heavyService = Yii::$container->get(HeavyServiceInterface::class);
        }

        return $this->heavyService;
    }
}
```

This is way more clean approach than one I used before. It's not perfect, but with Yii limitations its enough.